# Select query to display a row based on getting maximum date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this below query

```
 Select  distinct    
     a.Item_Name, b.Item_Rate, b.professional_Charge,
     c.discount, c.discount_Type,
     a.Dept_ID, c.Discount_Applicability, 
     c.Effective_Date, b.Effective_Date
 From 
     Item_M a
 left outer join 
     Rate_M b on a.Item_Code = b.Bill_Item and b.Rate_Cat_ID = 'GEN'
 left outer join 
     Discount_M c on a.Item_Code = c.Item_Code and c. Pay_Type_Id='CS'
 Where 
     a.Item_code = 'ABS002' 
     and c.Effective_Date <= GETDATE()
     and b.Effective_Date <= GETDATE()
 group by  
     a.Item_Name, b.Item_Rate, b.professional_Charge,
     c.discount, c.discount_Type,
     a.Dept_ID, c.Discount_Applicability, c.Effective_Date, b.Effective_Date
 order by 
     c.Effective_Date, b.Effective_Date desc
```

The output is as shown below:

```
 Item_Name  Item_Rate   professional_Charge discount    discount_Type   Dept_ID Discount_Applicability  Effective_Date  Effective_Date
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ABSESS I & D 75          NULL                 0           P             CBN     I                   2014-04-06 12:34:36.530    2014-04-09 15:15:56.367
 ABSESS I & D 440         NULL                 0           P             CBN    I                    2014-04-06 12:34:36.530    2014-04-07 15:15:56.367
 ABSESS I & D 75          NULL                 0           P             CBN    I                    2014-04-09 16:36:05.790    2014-04-09 15:15:56.367
 ABSESS I & D 440         NULL                 0           P             CBN    I                    2014-04-09 16:36:05.790    2014-04-07 15:15:56.367
```

Now the expected output what I need is to get one row where both effective date is maximum, i.e in this above output I need to display the **3rd** row in the output. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You only want one row, or the same number of rows but ordered by max of E.D. ?

Comment: I need only one row having max E.D for both

Comment: What are the rules for "E.D. for both"? Like, if you added 1 more row and the first ED was 2014-04-06 and the second was 2014-04-10, would you then want the new row, or still the 3rd row?  What if those values were switched?

Comment: I just want the row where in Both E.D is maximum it might not be 3rd row always.

Comment: Understood, but in my example one value is less than others in that column and the second value is the greatest in that column.  Would you want the new row since it has the greatest value in the second column EVEN THOUGH it does NOT have the greatest value in the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with SQL Server 2008 it is time for you to learn window functions. The one that I would use in your situation is a ROW_NUMBER() (although RANK can be used as well). You should also learn how to use CTE (common table expressions). They are real life savers in the modern SQL. If you apply this knowledge to your problem, the query will look as simple as this one:

```
; with b AS(
SELECT Item_Rate, Bill_Item, 
professional_Charge, 
Effective_Date, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Bill_Item ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC) rn
FROM Rate_M WHERE Rate_Cat_ID = 'GEN' and Effective_Date <= GETDATE()),
c AS 
(SELECT discount, Item_Code,
discount_Type,
Discount_Applicability, 
Effective_Date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Code ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC) rn
FROM Discount_M WHERE Pay_Type_Id='CS' and Effective_Date <= GETDATE())
 Select  
     a.Item_Name, b.Item_Rate, b.professional_Charge,
     c.discount, c.discount_Type,
     a.Dept_ID, c.Discount_Applicability, 
     c.Effective_Date, b.Effective_Date
 From 
     Item_M a
 left outer join 
     b on a.Item_Code = b.Bill_Item and b.rn = 1
 left outer join 
     c on a.Item_Code = c.Item_Code and c.rn = 1
 Where 
     a.Item_code = 'ABS002' 
 order by 
     c.Effective_Date, b.Effective_Date desc
```

Comment: When i execute this query it is showing error as invalid Bill_item,Red underline on b.Bill_item and c.Item_code

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have added the missing columns to the CTE c and CTE b